# Complexidade temporal de algoritmo palíndromo recursivo

Tags: java, recursão, complexidade-de-algoritmo

Preciso analisar o consumo de tempo do meu algoritmo, para um vetor de tamanho `n = f - i + 1`, através de uma recursão, para então definir uma formula fechada.

```
public class ehpalindromo {
    public static boolean ehPalindromo(String palavra, int i, int f) {
        //verificar se palavra vazia é vetor unitário com espaço ou vetor vazio(enter)
            boolean iguais = palavra.charAt(i) == palavra.charAt(f); //t1 + t2
            return iguais && (f - i <= 2 ? true : ehPalindromo(palavra, i + 1, f - 1)); //t3 + t4 + t5 + (t6) 
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Digite uma palavra para verificarmos se eh um palindromo ou nao: ");
        String palavra = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Digite o início e o fim da sequência a ser analisada: ");
        int i = sc.nextInt();
        int f = sc.nextInt();
        if(ehPalindromo(palavra, i, f)){
            System.out.println(palavra + " eh palindromo");
        }else {
            System.out.println(palavra + " nao eh palindromo");
        }
    }
}
```

Primeiro, contei as instruções do algoritmo. Assim, cheguei à seguinte recursão:

> ```
> F(n) = { a, se n =< 1; a + F(n-2), se n > 1
> ```
>
> Base:  a, se n =< 1 || Passo: a + F(n-2), se n > 1

Em que "a" corresponde ao somatório das instruções constantes.

Segundo, expandi a recorrência:

> ```
> F(0) = a;
> F(1) = a;
> F(2) = a + F(0) = a + a = 2a;
> F(3) = a + F(1) = a + a = 2a;
> F(4) = a + F(2) = a + 2a = 3a;
> F(5) = a + F(3) = a + 2a = 3a;
> F(6) = a + F(4) = a + 3a = 4a;
> ```

Dessa forma, cheguei, empiricamente, à formula fechada:

> ```
> F(n) = a + (n/2)a; porém, esta só funciona quando n é par, pois para n impar, ela seria F(n) = a + ((n-1)/2)a.
> ```

Gostaria de saber se contei as instruções de forma correta e como proceder para chegar à formula fechada.

Comment: Essa contagem empírica é não confiável. Você deveria usar a prova da indução matemática nesse caso, faltou só o passo indutivo. E você poderia simplificar o resultado de `F(n)` com a função floor, o arrendondamento para baixo. `F(n) = a*(1 + floor(n/2))`. Também creio que, dado o curto circuito, a definição da sua `F(n)` apresente um valor distinto de `a` na base da recursão

Comment: Sem falar que esse é o maior tempo de execução, não palíndromos executam mais rapidamente

Comment: Mas já não foram postos o passo indutivo e a base? Como considerar o melhor caso? Sim, preciso usar indução para provar a formula fechada

Comment: Se bem que não se usa indução para encontrar a formula fechada, certo? Mas somente para prová-la

Comment: Na indução matemática, existem 3 passos: base, recursão, passo indutivo. Você pôs a base é a recursão. O passo indutivo é o modo que você faz para provar que, se vale para `k`, vale para `k+1`.

Comment: Pois é, eu creio que, sobre uma conjectura, você usa a indução para provar essa conjectura.

Comment: Partindo de F(n) como verdadeiro provo então que F(n+2) também é verdade? Com isso cheguei a F(n+2) = 2a + F(n-2). Estou preso nesse ponto. Faz algum sentido? Como proceder?

Comment: Respondi a grosso modo, merece um carinho maior. Espero que seu ponto de dúvida tenha sido tratado correta e claramente. Espero feedback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para demonstrar uma fórmula derivada da recorrência, você precisa da conjectura (a fórmula derivada definida acima, que queremos provar) e de 3 outras características:

1. Fórmula recorrente;
2. Base da recursão;
3. Passo indutivo.

> Como o AP já demonstrou conhecimento nós dois primeiros pontos, não entrarei em detalhes agora.

### Passo indutivo

Suponha que a conjectura funcione para `f(x)`; usando a recursão, provamos que ela também funciona para `f(x + 1)`.

No caso, a conjectura é, para este caso:

[image: F(x) = a*(1 + floor(x/2))]

Supondo que seja verdade para `F(x)`. Para avaliar um palíndromo de tamanho `x+2`, será necessário fazer `a` passos a mais (dado pela fórmula recorrente). Portanto:

[image: F(x+2) = a + F(x) = a + a*(1 + floor(x/2)) = a*(1+1+floor(x/2)) = a*(1+floor( (x+2)/2 ))]

> CQD.

O passo indutivo funciona para `F(0)` e `F(1)`, portanto a conjectura se demonstra correta.

Demonstrar o passo indutivo válido para `F(0)` e `F(1)` fica como dever de casa para o leitor ;-)

Comment: Jefferson, o problema está no fato de que não posso utilizar a função floor, pois nossa prova não será programada. Como posso substituí-la?

Comment: Usando a notação matemática que parece um colchete sem a parte de cima; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions?wprov=sfti1; essa é uma função matemática não continua devidamente descrita para os reais e racionais. O `Math.floor` advém da descrição matemática direta, não é algo inventado apenas no âmbito das linguagens de programação

Comment: Então, F(n) = a + F(n-2) também faz parte da base? E não somente F(0) e F(1)? Com isso a recursão seria F(n) = ((n/2)+1)a ? Pode marcar na sua resposta cada  uma dessas partes, por gentileza?

Comment: Base são só `F(0)` e `F(1)`, pensei que você já tivesse entendido esse conceito, mas me enganei. `F(n) = F(n-2) + a` é uma consequência da fórmula recursiva, mas ela só se aplica a `n>=2`. Para que a fórmula recursiva/recorrência aborde todo o domínio dos naturais, normalmente se escreve `F(n+2) = F(n) + a`. Com exceção das definições descriminadas acima, todo o resto está na resposta devidamente destacado. Sair de `F(0)` e `F(1)` com o passo indutivo foi suprimido da minha resposta por: (a) trivialidade, muito simples fazer; (b) prestar uma ajuda rápida.

Comment: Demonstrar o passo indutivo válido para `F(0)` e `F(1)` fica como dever de casa para o leitor ;-)

Comment: @CaioIgnm , com fórmulas LaTeX deixando tudo mais bonito