# O que é assíntota?

Tags: terminologia, matemática, ciência-da-computação

[Em uma resposta veio o termo assintótica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/268362/101). Em comentário veio uma definição.

Acho que seria ter aqui uma definição mais completa. Mas o foco da pergunta é até mais simples:

Em português claro, ainda que impreciso, o que isso quer dizer para o programador que não tem uma boa base matemática? Por que isso importa para ele?

Para o programador médio isto não é claro e o que isto importa:

> Em matemática, uma assíntota/assímptota de uma curva C é um ponto ou uma curva de onde os pontos de C se aproximam à medida que se percorre C Quando C é o gráfico de uma função, em geral o termo assímptota refere-se a uma reta.

Comment: `lim x-> N F(x)/G(x) = k` para `N pertencente R + { -infinito , +infinito }` e `k pertencente a R*` implica que `G` é assíntota da função `F` no ponto `N` (ou nos infinitos). Não está totalmente certo mas é bem próximo

Comment: E nada claro :D

Comment: [A assíntota de Aquiles é a tartaruga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno's_paradoxes?wprov=sfti1https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno's_paradoxes?wprov=sfti1)

Comment: Cada vez menos claro :D :D :D

Comment: Há como adicionar um exemplo para essa sua definição ? @Maniero

Comment: @Fernando essa pergunta fornece exemplos de assíntotas para a complexidade temporal de um algoritmo, e as respostas tratam de outros algoritmos também: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/236960/64969

Comment: @Fernando não sei se é o foco, mas é uma sugestão para quem for responder.

Comment: Esse termo foi empregado nessa nota: Note aqui mais uma propriedade matemática que afasta as possibilidades reais da teoria, obrigando o sujeito que usa a
estatística gaussiana a platonificar. CONTINUA...

Comment: No mundo real, por limite de tempo, recursos ou disponibilidade de dados, somos quase
sempre obrigados a trabalhar com tamanhos pequenos de amostras, bem longe de serem considerados razoáveis para boas
aproximações, no sentido da “Lei dos Grandes Números” e do “Teorema Central do Limite”. CONTINUA ...

Comment: Ou seja, não vivemos na
`assíntota`. Frequentemente, em cursos de estatística, os professores estipulam um número mágico, como n=30, como sendo
suficientemente grande para permitir boas aproximações. É claro que isto só faz sentido se algumas fortes hipóteses sobre a
natureza das variáveis forem feitas a priori, como crer que elas têm comportamento de Mediocristão (muitas vezes uma forte
Platonificação): uma “casca de banana” para cair na falácia lúdica.  http://www.econ.puc-rio.br/uploads/adm/trabalhos/files/Bruno_B_de_Oliveira.pdf

Answer (score 39, accepted):

## Um conto grego

> A assíntota de Aquiles é a tartaruga

> Corolário do [Paradoxo de Zeno](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno%27s_paradoxes)

Um dia, Aquiles, o Herói, e uma tartaruga discutiram. A tartaruga afirmou para Aquiles que, se ela começasse na frente, ela iria vencer uma corrida de qualquer distância contra o Herói. Curioso, Aquiles perguntou

-Por que disso? Se eu sou mais rápido que você, eu irei vencer.

Para então a tartaruga responder:

-Se eu começar na frente, você precisa primeiro alcançar a posição que eu estava. Mas até você chegar lá, eu terei andado, estarei mais adiante. Então, você deverá chegar a minha nova posição, e eu estarei na sua frente. Então você precisará de infinitos passos desses até **chegar** em mim, pois então para me ultrapassar precisará de mais do que infinitos passos.

[image: Lide com isso, Aquiles]

## Noção informal de assíntota

No paradoxo de Zeno, não importa quantas vezes Aquiles tente ultrapassar a tartaruga, ele nunca conseguirá. Pois, a cada passo, Aquiles está se aproximando da tartaruga. Aquiles se torna assintoticamente próximo da tartaruga.

Veja os seguinte infográfico, evolução das posições de Aquiles e da tartaruga:

[image: Evolução das posições de Aquiles e da tartaruga pelo tempo]

Dá para perceber que Aquiles fica cada vez mais próximo da tartaruga a cada passagem de tempo. A esse tipo de comportamento nós chamamos de **assíntota**. Daí, *a assíntota de Aquiles é a tartaruga*.

Quando você quer saber o comportamento geral de uma função, você quer saber qual a *assíntota* da função. Por exemplo:

[image: metade de: x ao quadrado menos x]

Ao infinito, essa função tende a ter o mesmo comportamento que `x^2`. Então podemos dizer que o comportamento de `f(x) = (x^2 - x)/2` é assintoticamente `x^2`.

### Isso tem aplicação prática?

Bem, isso quer dizer que o **bubble sort** piora tão rápido quando o **insertion sort**, e também que o **merge sort** será melhor em casos maiores. Mais tarde, na seção **Por que isso importa para o programador?**, eu detalharei mais.

### Como identificar assíntotas?

De modo geral, você precisa de um "Aquiles" e de uma "tartaruga". A tartaruga será a assíntota de Aquiles.

A função dada como exemplo ela se aproxima de `x^2`, mas nunca chega nela.

Outro caso também, eu poderia pegar a função `1/x`. No infinito positivo, ela tende a ser zero, mas nunca o é:

[image: Desenho da função hiperbólica 1/x]

Note que quando `x=10`, a função vale `0.1`. Quando `x=80`, a função por sua vez agora valeria `0.0125`. Ficando cada vez mais próxima de 0, mas nunca de fato chegando lá.

## Por que isso importa para o programador?

Em um mundo normal de aplicações corporativas que não se preocupam em calcular qual o desconto (em porcentual) que eu devo aplicar no preço de venda para que o valor com o ICMS-ST alcance o total de R$10,00 no preço final (dica: tem uma fórmula que condensa a soma infinita), assíntotas servem basicamente para descrever comportamentos de algoritmos.

Então, para o programador médio, o que importa é **comportamento assintótico**, normalmente associado à complexidade temporal/espacial de um algoritmo.

A seguir, uma lista de perguntas que flertam com esse conceito (o autor sabendo disso ou não):

- [Como provar a ordem assintótica de um algoritmo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/236960/64969)
- [Existe algum algoritmo de ordenação que execute realmente em O(n)?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/265964/64969)
- [Consumo de tempo em código cúbico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/240472/64969)
- [Como melhorar o desempenho de meu código com "for"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/268296/64969)
  Nota especial: nessa pergunta, o autor acreditava que ter 3 `for` aninhados um dentro do outro era sinal de ineficiência, mas ele não havia percebido que estava no melhor possível matematicamente para iterar em uma coleção "cúbica" de dados
- [Complexidade temporal de algoritmo palíndromo recursivo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/240423/64969)
- [Qual a melhor implementação do 'Algoritmo MergeSort'?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/235616/64969)

Em todos os casos, se pede algo em relação ao comportamento assintótico (ou como parte da resposta, ou como parte da pergunta).

Também vale para o programador saber que comportamento assintótico nem sempre é tudo. As vezes temos constantes escondidas que, quando não se está "perseguindo tartarugas no infinito", se tornam muito mais importantes. Por exemplo, o **quick sort** possui o tempo de execução normalmente mais rápido do que o **merge sort**.

### Como provar a ordem assintótica de um algoritmo?

> **Esta pergunta já tem uma resposta aqui:**

> [Como provar a ordem assintótica de um algoritmo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/236960/64969) 3 respostas

## Formalmente, o que é uma assíntota?

Uma assíntota é um ponto ou curva para o qual uma função tende. Por exemplo, o centro é a assíntota para a seguinte função polar exponencial:

[image: função f(t) = e^(-0.1 t)]

Ela é plotada assim:

[image: plotagem da função f(t) = e^(-0.1 t)]

Quanto maior o θ, mais próxima a função fica de `(0,0)`. Então `(0,0)` é a assíntota de `f(t) = e^(-0.1 t)`.

Uma curva pode interceptar sua assíntota. Por exemplo, `f(x) = sen(10*x)/x + x` tem como assíntota `g(x) = x`:

[image: f(x) = sen(10*x)/x + x tem como assíntota g(x) = x]

Nem toda assíntota precisa ser uma reta, mas pode ser uma curva. Como o caso de `f(x) = |1/x| + x**2`, cuja assíntota nos infinitos é `g(x) = x**2`:

[image: plotagem de f(x) = |1/x| + x**2 e da assíntota g(x) = x**2]

Então, a assíntota `A` de uma função `F` é um valor (exemplo da espiral) ou função (outros dois exemplos) que, dada a evolução de `F` em termo de alguma variável, `F` se aproxima arbitrariamente próxima de `A`.

### Como descobrir uma assíntota de uma função?

Eu normalmente uso os seguintes passos (para funções que usam coordenadas cartesianas, não polares) para descobrir a ordem da assíntota:

1. conjecture `OA`
2. divida<sup>*</sup> `F/OA` ou `OA/F`
3. se errou, repita

A divisão, entretanto, não pode ser feita de qualquer forma. Normalmente, se deseja saber qual o comportamento extremo da função, então a divisão é com o limite da variável indo ao infinito. Nesse caso de comportamento no infinito, `OA` é da mesma ordem da assíntota de `F` se elas forem co-dominantes [conforme definida nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/237026/64969):

[image: verificando dominância entre duas funções]

Também condensado [nessa resposta do @Isac](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/237177/64969) para a mesma pergunta (obs: com `c != 0`):

[image: verificando co-dominância]

Descoberta a ordem, o valor obtido pela divisão é o coeficiente do maior termo. Isso significa que o termo mais significante da assíntota tem coeficiente conhecido, `c`. Agora, remova o termo mais significativa e calcule novamente. Como?

Bem, achamos `OA` a função co-dominante de `F`. Sabemos que `F = OA * c + G`, para `c = lim OA/F`. Então, agora, é achar o valor da assíntota de `G` e somar a `c*OA`, fazendo isso recursivamente até que, em algum momento, `lim G = 0`. Essa será a curva da assíntota de `F`.

#### Exemplo

Para `f(x) = x + sen(10*x)/x`. Vamos primeiro supor que a ordem da função assintótica `OA` é `x**2`:

[image: Verificando a dominância f(x) = x + sen(10*x)/x e x**2]

Essa divisão dá 0, portanto `OA` domina `f(x)`. Portanto, a primeira conjectura da ordem da função assintótica deu errado. Nesse caso, repitamos.

Vamos agora supor que a ordem da função assintótica `OA` é `x`:

[image: Verificando a dominância f(x) = x + sen(10*x)/x e x]

Eles são co-dominantes, então a ordem assintótica é, realmente, `OA`. Para o próximo passo, precisamos remover `c*OA` de `f(x)` e verificar `g(x)`:

[image: Calculando g(x)]

Chegamos a conclusão que `g(x) = sen(10 x)/x`. Agora, precisamos de outro termo para definir a assíntota de `g(x)`?

[image: Verificando se g(x) se anula no infinito]

Não, não precisamos. Portanto, `A(x) = x` é a assíntota para `f(x) = x + sen(10*x)/x`.

### Existem outras assíntotas que não as do infinito?

Sim, existem. Normalmente, elas se encontram em pontos de descontinuidade.

Tome a hipérbole `f(x) = 1/x`:

[image: Desenho da função hiperbólica 1/x]

Ela apresenta descontinuidade em `x = 0`. Portanto, o ponto `x = 0` é um candidato a ser uma *assíntota vertical* da função. Para achar uma assíntota vertical no ponto `x = a`, é preciso atender um desses quatro critérios:

[image: fórmulas critério para assíntota vertical em x = a]

A função deve tender ao infinito (positivo ou negativo) quando `x` tender ao valor `a`, seja o limite pela esquerda ou o limite pela direita.

No caso da hipérbole, quando `x -> 0` pela direita, `f(x) -> +infinito`. Isso já é o suficiente para considerar `x = 0` hipérbole vertical de `1/x`.

---

Fontes das imagens:

- Testudo marginata (GPL): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Nacht_006.jpg
  O gif [lide com isso, Aquiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0UNy.gif) portanto também deve ser usada sob a GPL
- 1 sobre `x`: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Hyperbola_one_over_x.svg
- Aquiles e a tartaruga: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Zeno_Achilles_Paradox.png
- Plotagem das funções obtidas de consultas ao WolframAlph:

  - [`f(t) = e^(-0.1 t)`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+polar+r%3De**(-0.1*theta),+theta+in+%5B380,+400%5D)
  - [`f(x) = sin(10*x)/x + x` vs `g(x) = x`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+f(x)+%3D+sin(10*x)%2Fx+%2B+x,+g(x)+%3D+x,+x+in+%5B1,+10%5D)
  - [`f(x) = |1/x| + x**2` vs `g(x) = x**2`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+f(x)+%3D+%7C1%2Fx%7C+%2B+x**2,+g(x)+%3D+x**2,+in+%5B-2,+2%5D)

Comment: E vem ele com as dissertações :) Amanhã eu leio, agora vou embarcar

Comment: Pra você: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0UNy.gif , haha

Comment: +1 pela historinha da tartaruga que elucidou!

Comment: @RafaelSalomão nunca mais olhará para tartarugas da mesma forma, haha

Comment: Acho que alguém ganhará um *bounty*, mas só depois do carnaval, o povo tá de férias :)

Answer (score 14):

Vou ser o mais breve e o mais simples possível e me concentrar em responder:

1. **O que isso quer dizer para o programador que não tem uma boa base matemática?**

   Este é o meu caso, não considero ter uma boa base matemática. Mas para mim, o conceito: **assíntota** me leva a pensar na **Notação Assintótica** tem relação com a **análise de algoritmo** e é usado como uma **ferramenta de análise** para o fim de realizar: **Análise Assintótica**. Desta forma, podemos assumir que:

   > Em geral, cada passo em uma descrição em pseudocódigo ou implementação em linguagem de alto nível corresponde a um pequeno número de oprações primitivas (exceto para chamadas de métodos, naturalmente). Assim, podemos realizar uma análise simplificada de um algoritmo escrito em pseudocódigo que estima o número de operações primitivas executadas, execeto por um fator constante, contando os passos do pseudocódigo (mas deve-se ter cuidado uma vez que uma linha de pseudocódigo pode denotar vários passos em alguns casos).[[Goodrich, Michael; Tamassia, Roberto - 2007](https://www.estantevirtual.com.br/peruibelivros/michael-t-goodrich-e-roberto-tamassia-estruturas-de-dados-e-algoritmos-em-java-4a-edicao-770551203), 159 p.]

   Para isso usamos a **Notação Assintótica**, um bom exemplo: Big-O (veja definição aqui: [[**Luiz Vieira - 56868**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56868/6789)], muito bem respondida por sinal), ômega: Ω e theta: θ são bem convenientes porque permitem a concentração nos aspectos gerais, em vez dos detalhes.
2. **Por que isso importa para ele?**

   Quando assumimos o papel, isto é, usamos o "boné" de programador é muito importante, na **análise de algoritmos** concentrar-se na taxa de crescimento do tempo de execução.

   E é importante sabermos diferenciar algoritmos eficientes e ineficientes, é natural fazer esta distinção entre os algoritmos que rodam em tempo polinominal e aqueles que requerem tempo exponencial respectivamente.

   > Ou seja, faz-se a distinção entre algoritmos que rodam em tempo O(n<sup>c</sup>) para alguma contante c > 1 e aquele cujo tempo de execução é O(b<sup>n</sup>) para alguma contante b > 1. ([[Goodrich, Michael; Tamassia, Roberto - 2007](https://www.estantevirtual.com.br/peruibelivros/michael-t-goodrich-e-roberto-tamassia-estruturas-de-dados-e-algoritmos-em-java-4a-edicao-770551203)]).

   Com base nisso podemos usar o gráfico de complexidade abaixo para fazer a distinção visualmente.

   [image: Gráfico que apresenta a relação da Notação Big-O (grande Ó) e as suas complexidades]
   <sub>Figura: Gráfico que apresenta a relação da Notação Big-O e suas complexidades

   FONTE: [[Maniero - 268308](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/268308/6789)]</sub>

   E é claro que é importante para o programador saber que:

   > Pode-se usar a **Notação Assintótica** O (Big-O) para ordenar classes de funções por seu crescimento assintótico.

   Isto é, se uma função f(n) precede uma função g(n) na sequência conforme a tabela abaixo:

   > *f(n) é O(g(n))*

   [image: Tabela: sequência ordenada das classes de funções por seu crescimento assintótico]
   <sub>Tabela: sequência ordenada das classes de funções por seu crescimento assintótico

   FONTE: Elaboradas pelo autor da resposta.</sub>

---

<sub>**Nota<sup>1</sup>**: quanto a base matemática, diremos que devemos manter o hábito de praticar, fazendo listas de exercícios, das funções (fatos matemáticos) aplicáveis na **análise de algoritmo**.</sub>

<sub>**Nota<sup>2</sup>**: Na tabela cima, assumi o critério de eficiente e ineficiente apenas por ser bem convenientes porque é para concentração nos aspectos gerais, em vez dos detalhes.</sub>

---

**Referência**: 
<sub>[**Goodrich, Michael; Tamassia, Roberto -  2007**], 4 ed. - Porto Alegre: Bookman © 2007, **[Estrutura de dados e algoritmos em Java](https://www.estantevirtual.com.br/peruibelivros/michael-t-goodrich-e-roberto-tamassia-estruturas-de-dados-e-algoritmos-em-java-4a-edicao-770551203)**: 4 Edição.</sub>
<sub>[**Maniero - 268308**], Stack Overflow , **[Resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/268308/6789)**: Como melhorar o desempenho de meu código com “for”?. Acesso em: 14 jan. 2018</sub>
<sub>[**Luiz Vieira - 56868**], Stack Overflow , **[Resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56868/6789)**: Definição da notação “Big O”. Acesso em: 14 jan. 2018</sub>