# Ordem Crescimento

Tags: c, complexidade-de-algoritmo

Necessitava de ajuda para perceber qual o cálculo correto da ordem de crescimento deste excerto de código (função de N=2^M)

```
int sum=0;
 for (int i = 0; i < = N; i++)
   for(j = 1; j <= N; j++)
     for(k = 1; k <= N; k=k+j)
       sum++;
```

Os dois primeiros ciclos FOR tem ordem de crescimento O(N) mas no caso do terceiro ciclo FOR fiquei com dúvidas. E depois será necessário somar todas as ordens de crescimento a fim de obter a solução final.

Comment: No terceiro laço, você terá `O(floor(N/j))` passos para cada `j`, portanto será o somatório com `j` variando dentro de `[1,N]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como você mesmo havia suspeitado, a segunda iteração afeta a terceira iteração. Sendo mais específico, para todo `j` entre `[1, N]`, a terceira iteração será repetida em torno de `N/j` vezes. Já a primeira iteração é completamente alheia e independente a isso.

Focando nas duas iterações mais externas, para cada `i`, elas serão executadas a seguinte quantidade de vezes:

[image: somatório de N/k para k em <code>[1,N]</code>]

Isso, então, é `N` vezes uma parte de uma [série harmônica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)?wprov=sfti1). Como foi informado que `N= 2^M`, então a soma da série harmônica até `N` vai dar `1+M/2` (prova no [artigo linkado](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)?wprov=sfti1)). Aplicando à fórmula acima, temos então `O(N(1 + M/2))`.

Como a primeira fórmula é independente, ela fará `N` repetições daquela ordem de grandeza, portanto rodará em `O(N*N(1 + M/2))`. Como estamos em notação [Big-O](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56836/64969), e como `M = lg N`, então a ordem de crescimento [assintótica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/268409/64969) da função é `O(N^2 * lg N)`