# Complexidade de algoritmos - Notação Big O

Tags: complexidade-de-algoritmo

A função `f(n) = n3 + 2` domina assintoticamente a função `g(n) = 200n2 + 5`,
para um valor de n suficientemente grande. 
Ou seja, `g(n)` é `O(f(n))`

Como posso provar que essa afirmação é verdadeira?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como provar a ordem assintótica de um algoritmo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/236960/como-provar-a-ordem-assint%c3%b3tica-de-um-algoritmo)

Comment: Veja nessa pergunta que eu linkei como duplicata, todas as respostas de lá abordam isso.

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/268409/64969

Comment: Eu li todas essas publicações, mas mesmo assim não entendi --'

Comment: Dê uma olhada com muito carinho na resposta do Isac. Tente fazer os cálculos junto com ele. Eu particularmente acho que a resposta dele é a melhor das 3 para tentar entender como provar a ordem assintótica de funções.

Answer (score 3):

Provar que `g(n)` é `O(f(n))` é o mesmo que dizer que existem constantes `c` e `n0` (ambas positivas) tais que

```
0 ≤ g(n) ≤ cf(n), para todo n ≥ n0
```

Ou seja, temos que provar que

```
0 ≤ 200n2 + 5 ≤ c(n3 + 2), para todo n ≥ n0
0 ≤ 200n2 + 5 ≤ cn3 + 2c, para todo n ≥ n0
```

Observe que `0 ≤ 200n2 + 5` é redundante, pois `200n2 + 5` é sempre positivo. Logo, é suficiente analisar apenas

```
200n2 + 5 ≤ cn3 + 2c, para todo n ≥ n0
```

O ponto agora é encontrar as contantes `c` e `n0` que satisfaçam a condição anterior. Tenha em mente que qualquer par de valores `c` e `n0` que satisfaça a condição é válido.

Se escolhermos `c = 100` e `n0 = 1`, a condição será válida:

```
200n2 + 5 ≤ 100n3 + 200, para todo n ≥ 1
```

Outra escolha seria `c = 69` e `n0 = 1`

```
200n2 + 5 ≤ 69n3 + 138, para todo n ≥ 1
```

Portanto, como existe um par de contantes `c` e `n0` que satisfaz `0 ≤ g(n) ≤ cf(n)`, para todo `n ≥ n0`, então `g(n)` é `O(f(n))`.

**Referências**

CORMEN, T. H. et al. *Algoritmos: teoria e prática.* 3 ed. Rio de Janeiro: Elsevier, 2012.